# Java multiplication of negative numbers

Tags: java, multiplication

In normal maths terms, -1756046391 * -1291488517 will equal 2267913749295792147.

When i enter the exact same equation in java, i get the answer: -1756046391 * -1291488517 = 19.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Overflow.  Check out Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Try this: `-1756046391L * -1291488517`. You are using unchecked operations on primitive ints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overflow.

Check out Integer.MAX_VALUE.  An Integer in Java is a 32 bit 2s complement value.  You can't exceed the MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with very large numbers, you need to make sure the data type you used is big enough to store that number. In java you have these primitive number types:

```
type:                      min:                      max:
byte                       -128                       127
short                    -32768                     32767
int              -2,147,483,648             2,147,483,647
long -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

So as you can see, your number would just about fit into a `long`. But you're bound to go over that, so you should probably use the `BigInt` class instead:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 1):

Either use longs as others said, or if that is not enough for your application, consider using `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Post the exact code you used to reproduce this.

You are most likely using ints. Use longs, because 2267913749295792147 is too big to fit in an int.

Comment: He should use a BigInt object, since his number*5 would overflow a long.